# How can I iterate over foreign keys in a Django dictionary?

Tags: python, django

I am pretty new to programming and have a question about iterating over foreign keys in my Django view file.

models.py

```
class Site(models.Model):
    other fields.......
    sensor = models.ForeignKey("Sensor", blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

views.py

```
def site(request, site_name_slug):

    context_dict = {}

    empty_field = "<font color='LightGray'>No Data</font>"


    try:
        site = Site.objects.values().get(slug=site_name_slug)
        context_dict['site_slug'] = site_name_slug

        for key, value in site.iteritems():
            if value:
                context_dict[key] = value
            else:
                context_dict[key] = empty_field
```

Is it possible to do add something like this?

```
for key, value in (site.sensor).iteritems():
    if value:
        context_dict['sensor_%s' % key] = value
    else:
        context_dict['sensor_%s' % key] = value
```

So that I don't have to use if/else or try/except for every field in the sensor object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterating over model attributes when creating a template in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172722/iterating-over-model-attributes-when-creating-a-template-in-django)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### No, `ForeignKeys` provide one-to-many relationships.

In your model a given `Site` will only ever have *at most one* sensor. There is nothing to iterate over, so what you are asking doesn't make sense.

---

There is no need to specifically iterate through all of the `sensor`s fields to access them in the template, if you pass the page `site` into the template, for example as `current_site` you can access the sensor like so:

```
{{ current_site.sensor }}
```

To access a sensors field, (for example if a sensor had a field named "value") just append that, like so:

```
{{ current_site.sensor.value }}
```

Comment: Is it possible to create another dictionary from the sensor object that is associated with the site object and iterate over that?

Comment: @Murphysboro you shouldn't need to unless I'm missing something, just use dot notation to access the parts of the `sensor` itself.

Comment: I want to check each of the fields in sensor to see if they contain a value just like I do with the site fields in the example above.

Comment: That's cool about the dot notation though I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: No problems, if this helped feel free to upvote or accept to let future vistors know you found an answer to your problem.

Comment: @user764357 what about inline items are?