# Display column names in Django template without knowing them ahead of time

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a queryset that I am passing to Django. There are 100 columns or so. I want to render this single object as either an HTML list without knowing all the column names. I know I could use [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), but I want more control to do something like this within a TemplateView (with additional graphs):

```
<ul>
{% for obj in queryset %}
    <li>
    {% for column in obj %}
        [Name of Column]: {{ column }}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So I want to render both the name of the column and the column data without knowing the name of the column beforehand. Ordinary I'd do this:

```
<ul>
{% for obj in queryset %}
    <li>
        Column 1: {{ obj.column1 }}            
        Column 2: {{ obj.column2 }}            
        ...
        Column 100: {{ obj.column100 }}            
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But this is a bit tedious and requires writing out each column name by hand.

Comment: Pass `obj.__dict__` instead of `obj` to the template.

Comment: You could add a method to the object that allows you to iterate each column and its value from within the template: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172722/iterating-over-model-attributes-when-creating-a-template-in-django

Comment: Can you post sample data from your queryset?  This is fairly straightforward to implement but you have to add a table for `column names` that has a FK to your current query.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this

```
<ul>
{% for obj in queryset %}
    <li>
    {% for column in obj.column_set.all %}
        [Name of Column]: {{ column }}
    {% endfor %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this work `[Name of Column]`? That is just going to display`[Name of Column]` isn't it? Do you have any link on what that is, if it does indeed work?